# Synchronize gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, nullpointerexception

I am using PDT (php eclipse) with the aptana plugin to do FTP file transfers.  When I go to "Transfer Files" on a connection and then click the synchronize button sometimes it waits a bit then gives me java.lang.NullPointerException and freezes.  Once this has happened, synchronize wont work anymore for a long time.  In the past I have gotten it to work again, somehow.  Tho I keep closing eclipse and restarting and I cant get it to work anymore.  This is driving me crazy!!

This is at the top of the log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-09-11 23:23:48.061
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Generating Synchronize Status".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.<init>(Path.java:153)
    at com.aptana.ide.syncing.core.old.SyncModelBuilder.buildSyncFolder(SyncModelBuilder.java:128)
    at com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.old.views.SmartSyncDialog$14.run(SmartSyncDialog.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Aptana, have you tried asking on their support forums?

Comment: Did you find out something about this?